# DoWhile loop acts weird (to me). Can someone explain?

Tags: c#, do-while

I usually do Java programming, but wanted to test my luck with C# to see what it's like. I'm more of a novice programmer, so perhaps this is silly, but on my Do-While loop, why does it only work if I use && instead of || when trying to terminate my loop? To me, in Java, || would be used because you want either a capital OR lower-case "q" to terminate. I'm reading the termination as "Q" AND "q". Obviously this isn't the case since the loop terminates just fine. I just don't understand how that quite works.

```
namespace Testing_Grounds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string entry;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is an inventory screen");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Health Potions");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Mana Potions");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Revive Potions");
                Console.Write("Please enter the number of the item " +
                    "you would like to inspect, or enter \"Q\" to quit: ");
                entry = Console.ReadLine();

                if (entry.Equals("1"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Health Potions");
                }
                else if (entry.Equals("2"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mana Potions");
                }
            } while (entry != "Q" && entry != "q");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: it works exactly the same as in Java.

Comment: I suppose this is where I re-iterate that I'm a novice programmer. I went through to see if I had any counter examples, but they only exist in my "if" statements (in terms of OR vs. AND).

Comment: Novice programmers should assume that they are wrong. That's so often true in their case.

Comment: @ZachFiedler +1 Because you're cool. Keep coding :)

Comment: And I'm completely fine with being wrong, that doesn't mean I'm not going to double/triple check to be sure. I apologize if I come across as arrogant or disrespectful, given your reputation/accomplishments, but it never hurts to look. I was really more interested in an explanation as to why it works this way. I read it literally as "While entry does not equal Q OR while entry does not equal q."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` and `&&` work the same way in C# and Java in this respect.

`entry != "Q" && entry != "q"` (AND) will continue the loop when a character is different to both `Q` and `q` which is what you want.

`entry != "Q" || entry != "q"` (OR) is true for any character as a character is always different to either `Q` or `q` so the loop will never be terminated.

Comment: This helps my understanding a bit more. As I posted in the comments on the question, my counter example is during the use of an IF statement. I suppose I need to take some more time to analyze how the loops actually work and close out.

Comment: Well, one is "continue while true", the other "if true do this". They are quite similar and I'm sure you'll master that soon. Good luck!

Comment: I will most certainly keep that in mind. It's just slightly disheartening to learn that I've been reading it wrong for the past two courses of College level Java programming. But thank you regardless, this is incredibly useful!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference for `conditional operator` either in Java or in C# (or in any programming language) since those are elementary programming concept. You are understanding it wrong way.

What you are trying to do is

```
while (entry != "Q" && entry != "q");
```

So your `entry` variable can hold only one value at any point of instance (instance mean time). So at any time either it will be `Q` or `q` but not `both`. Rather you should do it like

```
while (entry != "Q" || entry != "q");
```

Moreover, your `entry` variable storing only one char value; so why declaring it as `string`. rather declare as `char` instead which would be memory efficient.

Comment: I will continue to improve the efficiency to the best of my ability as I progress. Initially, I had it pulling in an int value and it took a while to figure out how to do that:
In java I would just say
    int entry = stdIn.NextInt();
and call it a day. In C# (Unless I haven't found a way to do it), I had to learn how to use the parse commands.

Answer (score 1):

`do`/`while` loop condition specifies when loop should be executed again, not when it should be exited. That's why you need `&&`.

I'm pretty sure it works exactly the same way in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much; I think I'm starting to understand the fundamental aspect of it with each answer I read on here. More specifically, I have been looking at it from the stand of when the loop is terminated rather than when the loop continues. I will bear this in mind!

Answer (score 1):

The criterion is for continuation, not termination. If you used `||`, you would be saying "continue looping if entry isn't Q or it isn't q", which is always true (entry can't be both), so you would never exit. `&&` is the correct logic in both languages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm reading over all of these to help cement that fundamental piece of logic. I've been reading it wrong for the past two Java courses in college :/

Answer (score 1):

The `do ... while` loop works just fine. It will terminate when the statement in condition turns to false, as others said. The confusion with `||` and `&&` you experience here may be caused by different way of writing the same condition:

`entry != "Q" && entry != "q"`

is the same as

`!(entry == "Q" || entry == "q")`.

The [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) says:

> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.

Comment: Ha! I like that quote, it actually made me smile. I'll have to read more into De Morgan to understand that a bit better but I get the gist of it for now. 

I think part of my confusion is definitely my novice-ness, but also as you've mentioned, the different ways of getting to the same point. 

As others have posted though, I'm most certainly reading the loop from the wrong perspective. I look at it from a point of termination when I should be reading it from a point of continuation.

Comment: @ZachFiedler As a side note, the only loop I remember now that has the condition for termination and not continuation is [repeat...until](http://wiki.freepascal.org/REPEAT..UNTIL) from Pascal.